# Android Studio doesn't see my device

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't see my device in 'Choose device', it is also not present in adb.
I have USB debugging enabled, Google USB driver and and a driver for my phone installed. I tried killing and starting server but this doesn't help. Any suggestions? Thanks.

I have got a Huawei G300.

Comment: do you see your device after you write the `adb devices` command?

Comment: I sometimes experience this on my Windows laptop, a device which I have debugged cannot be found anymore. Solution to this I find when I manually reinstall the usb driver for the device provided in `android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver` through the Device Manager

Comment: Did you restart your machine after installing your drivers? check out this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ig7XZo1m_Jc

Comment: for some vendors you need to add the vendor-id to adb_usb.ini - on which OS are you?

Comment: 55597's tutorial helped, thank you all :)